# How to create SharePoint modern site template

Tags: pnp-powershell, site-template

I have to create the SharePoint modern site templates, that I can access from "From your organization templates. I have tried following PowerShell but it seems like pages are not getting applied

```
Connect-PnPOnline -UseWebLogin
Get-PnPSiteScriptFromWeb -url https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/POC -IncludeAll
$Json = Get-PnPSiteScriptFromWeb -url https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/POC -IncludeAll
$sc=Add-PnPSiteScript -Title "Department template" -Description "Department template" - 
Add-PnPSiteDesign -Title "Department template" -WebTemplate "68" -SiteScripts $sc,ID -Description "<Description displayed in Step 5>"enter code here
```

Article or script to create Site Template

Answer (score 2):

There's a limited number of actions that can be applied via site scripts/site designs, and if you are trying to provision pages using this method, you might need to look at using a Power Automate flow to enhance the provisioning process.

There is some documentation here that might be helpful

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-overview#pnp-provisioning-and-customization-using-power-automate

Also, there is an article outlining how you can invoke a PnP template using Flows and Azure Fuctions here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-pnp-provisioning